# Laravel Project - vCard extension appends .html on android after download

Tags: laravel, vcf-vcard

I am building a project on Laravel and its some kind of digital card project.

I have a button that downloads a vcard file with .vcf extension. I tested this on MAC and it works just fine. However when I click on same button on mobile devices, downloaded file has .vcf.html extension. And it shows data of vcf file as text. Here is my controller:

```
public function exportVCF($url){
    
    $user = User::where('url',$url)->first();
    $lastname = $user->name;
    $firstname = '';
    $additional = '';
    $prefix = '';
    $suffix = '';

    $vcard = new VCard();
    $vcard->addPhoneNumber($user->phone);
    $vcard->addName($lastname, $firstname, $additional, $prefix, $suffix);

    if($user->getCompany->count() > 0){
        $company_info = $user->getCompany->first();
        if($company_info->company_name != null){
            $vcard->addCompany($company_info->company_name);
        }

        if($company_info->title != null){
            $vcard->addJobTitle($company_info->title);
        }

        if($company_info->work_mail != null){
            $vcard->addEmail($company_info->work_mail, 'WORK');
        }

        if($company_info->work_phone != null){
            $vcard->addPhoneNumber($company_info->work_phone, 'WORK');
        }

        if($company_info->work_web_site != null){
            $vcard->addUrl($company_info->work_web_site);
        }

        if($company_info->address != null){
            $vcard->addAddress($company_info->address, 'WORK');
        }
    }
    $vcard->download();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After researching, i found solution at https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard/issues/91
It appears vcf file gets wrong headers.
Instead of downloading vcf file with `$vcard->download()` , you need to use :

```
$response = new Response();

// 4b. add response content and status code
$response->setContent($vcard);
$response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);

// 4c. add response headers
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/x-vcard');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', mb_strlen($vcard, 'utf-8'));

// 5. return the vcard
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in provided in https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard/issues/91
It has to do with setting the right headers for the download:

```
$content = $vcard->getOutput();

$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($content);
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/x-vcard');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.str_slug($name).'.vcf"');
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', mb_strlen($content, 'utf-8'));

return $response;
```